# Flyway H2 and MySql mismatch after upgrading

Tags: spring-boot, h2, flyway

I got myself in a deep mud :(

I wanted to upgrade gradle from 4 to 6.
This caused me upgrading spring, and eventually flyway and H2.

Now, unfortunantly, I get flyway errors on tests.

**Here is some info:**

```
 api "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.2.2.RELEASE"
api "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.2.2.RELEASE"
    api "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.2.2.RELEASE"
testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.2.2.RELEASE") {
    exclude (group: 'com.h2database', module: 'h2')
}

api("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38")
implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:6.4.2'
testImplementation("com.h2database:h2:1.4.199") {
  force = true
}
```

Before the upgrade, all worked fine. 
Now I get weird WARN about another version (though I am using the recommended) version, and lots or errors.:

```
 WARN  o.f.c.i.d.b.Database:53 - Flyway upgrade recommended: H2 1.4.200 is newer than this version of Flyway and support has not been tested. The latest supported version of H2 is 1.4.199.

ERROR o.f.c.i.c.DbMigrate:57 - Migration of schema "PUBLIC" to version 9 - fixCheckingAccountIndex failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code!


SQL State  : 42S22
Error Code : 42122
Message    : Column "INDEX" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP INDEX ACC_INDEX [42122-200]
Location   : db/migration/V9__fixAccountIndex.sql 
Line       : 1
Statement  : ALTER TABLE checking_account DROP INDEX BTA_CHECKING_ACC_INDEX
```

test-properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE;INIT=create schema if not exists \\"public\"\\; SET SCHEMA public;
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

When I run the application normally, with no tests, it all works fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks and Regards,

**EDIT**

I've been trying to understand why I get version 200 of h2.

On my depndecy tree:

```
gradle -q dependencies | grep h2
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.199 (n)
|    |    |         +--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.193 -> 1.4.200
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.199 -> 1.4.200
|    |    |         +--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.193 -> 1.4.200
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.199 -> 1.4.200
|    |    |         +--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.193 -> 1.4.200
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.199 -> 1.4.200
|    |    |         +--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.193 -> 1.4.200
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.199 -> 1.4.200
```

From some reason it uses the newer verison.

**EDIT 2020-05-26**

As reqeusted here is the error after upgrading to spring 2.3.0

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in com...SpringTestConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
Migration V9__IndexFix.sql failed
------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42S22
Error Code : 42122
Message    : Column "INDEX" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP INDEX ACC_INDEX [42122-200]
Location   : db/migration/V9__IndexFix.sql (.../resources/db/migration/V9__IndexFix.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : ALTER TABLE table1 DROP INDEX ACC_INDEX
```

The warnings of the compatibility which I complained at this post, are gone after the upgrade

Still this h2 error. on older versions it worked.
current versions:

org.flywaydb:flyway-core:6.4.1 (though in gradle I put 6.4.2)
com.h2database:h2:1.4.200

Comment: spring-boot-starter-test comes with a H2 dependency with the version 1.4.200. I assume this overrides your set dependency. Try to exclude the H2 dependency from spring-boot-starter-test.

Comment: i added this :  

```
testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${ver.spring}") {
        exclude (group: 'com.h2database', module: 'h2')
    }
```
And it still fetches 200 version.
even added force = true on the real depndency.

Comment: I think the warning about H2 is misleading. It's just a warning. The log says: "Migration of schema "PUBLIC" to version 9" fails. So migration up to version 8 of the schema was successful. Try to remove this 9th migration step and see what happens.

Comment: Tried searching for version 200 on gradle tree:
om.h2database:h2:1.4.199 -> 1.4.200

Is see this all around but no actual com.h2database:h2:200 anywhere...
Why do I get it?

Comment: gradle -q dependencies | grep h2
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.199 (n)
|    |    |         +--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.193 -> 1.4.200
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.199 -> 1.4.200
|    |    |         +--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.193 -> 1.4.200
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.199 -> 1.4.200
|    |    |         +--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.193 -> 1.4.200
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.199 -> 1.4.200
|    |    |         +--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.193 -> 1.4.200
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.4.199 -> 1.4.200

Comment: Thanks guys for your attempts to help me, I edited the question with new data

Comment: I've created a bare Gradle project with only your mentioned dependencies, your test properties and two migration files. One for creating table1 with one column and the index. The second for dropping the index as you did. It works flawlessly with Java 8 and 11. And it works for H2 1.4.199 and 1.4.200. And it works for Flyway 6.4.1 and 6.4.2. So it has to be something different that's not mentioned here in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Spring Boot dependencies to 2.3.0.RELEASE.

The 2.2.X had a dependency mismatch between an old flyway version (6.0.8) and an unsupported new H2 version (1.4.200).
Support for H2 1.4.200 came with Flyway 6.1.0.

And even if you specify a newer Flyway version - I think it is as ignored as the specified H2 version.

Edit:
Alternatively you can force specific versions in Gradle like this:

```
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            dependencySubstitution {
                substitute module('com.h2database:h2') with module('com.h2database:h2:1.4.199')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I upgraded to version 3.   most is working but still I get error from flyway on H2.  It worked on older versions

This script
ALTER TABLE table DROP INDEX CHECKING_ACC_INDEX

Seems to me no ALTER TABLE DROP INDEX is allowed.  but i was working.
And it is working on PROD with MySQL

Comment: Which version of Flyway and H2 is now used?

Comment: org.flywaydb:flyway-core:6.4.1 (though in gradle I put 6.4.2)
com.h2database:h2:1.4.200

but I see in the documentation https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html that ALTER TABLE DROP INDEX does not exist. But again, this is an old script that used to work properly before the upgrade.  
Any thoughts?

Comment: As you specified MySQL as H2 mode the command shall work as before. Is the error still exactly the same? Is there still the warning? Perhaps you update your question with the newest information.

Comment: I edited as you asekd.    Same issue.  The problem is not with MySQL - the problem is H2

Comment: Not update my answer but your question. The warning is gone, the versions have been updated, ...